# What is reference for in layout update file?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

I'm new to Magento, and am wondering what the reference tag is for in the [mylayout].xml file.

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="dennis/mijnblok" name="content" output="toHtml" template="oefening/all/Mijnblok.phtml" />
</reference>
```

If I change reference name to `content` it will not work.

But, when I change `name="content"` to `name="test"`, it does work.

So I'm wondering why, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

**Reference** element is used to link an already defined block in any layout XML. To add any child block to an existing block, to modify attributes of an existing block or to perform any action on an existing block, the reference element is used to link to the existing block. The reference element must have a name attribute which refers to the existing block’s name.

```
name="root"
name="head"
name="left"
name="right"
name="content"
name="footer"
and etc
```

These are predefined block in magento. you cannot use that name as a block name. if you use that then there is name conflict and your block will not shown.

Comment: Can't find root as a block?

Answer (score 2):

reference meaning you are going to using the already defined block.

By default all pages has following block

1.Header
 2.Content
 3.Left
 4.Right
 5.Footer

If you want to inculde some thing in the content block you use as content block as reference

```
<your_handle>
   <reference name="content">
     <!-- your block code -->
           <block type="dennis/mijnblok" name="block.unique.name" template="oefening/all/Mijnblok.phtml" />

   </reference>
</your_handle>
```

**Note :** Block name must be unique

Refer this [Tutorial](http://blog.belvg.com/layout-xml-directives-handles-block-reference-action-remove-update.html) you will get better understanding of the layout in magento

Comment: Thanks, but why is the root name always working, and the content name not?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be because `"content"` is actually the main content area in which you should be putting your `Mijnblok.html`

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
        </block>
    </block>
</block>
```